# How to make letters appear one by one in notepad using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

This is my first post in Stackoverflow. I don't know how to start but here is
my question: I am working for a rpg game using vbscript. I am using notepad
and did the letters appear one by one like this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad.exe", 3
WshShell.SendKeys ". L"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "t'"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " m"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "k"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " a"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "n"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "x"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "m"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "p"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e:"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "Y"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "u"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " a"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "n"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " a "
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "f"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " w"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "h"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "m"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "d"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "u"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "c"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s."
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " W"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "h"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " w"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " y"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "u"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " d"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o?"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "1-"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "I"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " w"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "y"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " f"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "n"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "d"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "m"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "u"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "r"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "c"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s."
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "2-"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "I"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " w"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " b"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "u"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "d"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " a "
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "m"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "a"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "l"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " h"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "o"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "u"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "s"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "e"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " w"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "i"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "t"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "h"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys " m"
WScript.Sleep(100)
WshShell.SendKeys "y"
```

This works nice but it is so much time consuming. So How can I do the same thing
without so many lines.

Note: I don't know the coding so can you explain with basics.

Comment: Start over and don't use SendKeys to put text in Notepad? Instead you could make a console program.

Comment: @crashmstr unless creating the worlds first notepad RPG is their aim? ;p

Answer (score 0):

In doubts, read docs e.g. [SendKeys Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx):

> To send a space, send the string " ".
>   **You can use `SendKeys` to send more than one keystroke at a time**. To do this, create a compound string argument that represents a
>   sequence of keystrokes by appending each keystroke in the sequence to
>   the one before it. For example, to send the keystrokes a, b, and c,
>   you would send the string argument "abc".

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad.exe", 3
WScript.Sleep 500            ' give Notepad enough time to start and activate its window
WshShell.SendKeys ". Let's make an example"
WScript.Sleep 500
```

Comment: Will that delay each keystroke though or just write all the text to notepad the minute it's activated?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this code :)

```
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Ws.run "Notepad.exe"
wscript.sleep 1000
ws.AppActivate "Notepad"
Msg = "HELLO !"& vbCRLF &_
"I'M WRITING RIGHT NOW THIS SPECIAL MESSAGE FOR YOU Letter by Letter !"& vbCRLF &_
"Good luck and Good bye from Hackoo !"

For x = 1 To Len(Msg)
    WScript.Sleep 100
    Ws.SendKeys Mid(Msg,x,1)
    WScript.Sleep 100
Next

Call SpeakVoice(Msg)

'--SpeakVoice--
Function SpeakVoice(msg)
Dim voice
Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
voice.speak msg
end Function
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `Else` does apart from duplicate code?

Comment: Is the `SpeakVoice()` part even relevant to the OPs original question?

Comment: @Lankymart No it's just a bonus from me LOL

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks to everyone! I managed to build a program for myself! If someone wants to letters appear one by one using vbscript , here is the program to [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ts5-Ur5nxWOUo2UWljcDRqeFk/view?usp=sharing)